# How can I disable lightbox2 on mobile

Tags: mobile, lightbox2

Just discovered this code and implementation of lightbox2 and added the needed code to some of my webpages.
Looks very good o desktop and also on tablet but I don't like the lightbox in mobile view.
The pictures that are shown on mobile are smaller than the 'normal' responsive view that I get when not using lightbox2.
So my question is in the title: How can I disable the lightbox on mobile?
Regards Arno

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible at this time. The Lightbox script on load will attach event handlers to the target images.

To get around this, you can use different markup on mobile and show hide the content with CSS media queries.

Comment: It's a good use case and something I'm looking into for the next version of the Lightbox script.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Maybe a fine option in a next version then. Thanks in advance!
Regards, Arno